# Want to batch move all files from directories into the parent directory and delete the subdirectory

Tags: windows, batch-file, move-semantics, xcopy

I have a Windows Directory with about 8000 subdirectories. In each subdirectory there is a single zip file. 
Is there a way I can batch script the move of each zip file to be moved to the parent directory, and then delete the subdirectory it was in? (Sub folder)
I know I can use xcopy to move files, but I'm not sure how to loop through the entire directory of sub directories.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /s *.zip') DO (
    MOVE "%%~fa" ..
    RD "%%~dpa"
)
```

Comment: This might suffer from the FOR problem where the filespec is processed multiple times. It is probably processing them as it goes.  A solution is to use the `FOR /F` command.