# Batch Script to delete files based on findstr regex

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I'm trying to delete some files with a batch script, based on a regular expression.  What I have is:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b | findstr MY_REGEX_HERE') DO ECHO %%a
```

I know my inner command works on its own, giving me the list of directories, but when I embed it in the for loop like this I get an error `| was unexpected at this time.`  Is piping not allowed within FOR loop commands?  Or do I need to escape it or something?

Any help on how I can do this would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b ^| findstr MY_REGEX_HERE') DO ECHO %%a
```

Escape the `|` using a `^` before it.

Comment: @Retsam - `^` has been one of the escape characters for batch files from a really long time as far as I know. May be for more than 15 years.

Comment: `%%a` is causing `%%a was unexpected at this time`.  
just `%a` works for me.

Answer (score -7):

The CMD processor is just too limited to do what you want here, pipe is not legal in this context. You could kludge it with replacing your ECHO stub with a CALL to another batch file, but even then you will still have problems. See [Want to batch move all files from directories into the parent directory and delete the subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385072/want-to-batch-move-all-files-from-directories-into-the-parent-directory-and-dele/18385638#18385638) for my quick comparion of scripting environments options.

Comment: It is perfectly legal when you escape it.

Comment: My bad -- forgot about escaping the pipe. CMD is still lousy for complex scripting though.