# Batch script to delete files with specific pattern names

Tags: batch-file

I need help in deleting files with specific patterns in a folder.

For example in `C:/program Files/` I have files like: `test_1.txt`, `test_2.txt`, `test_3.txt`, `test_4.txt`, `test_5.txt`.

I would like to delete the files from `test_2.txt` to `test_5.txt`.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch Script to delete files based on findstr regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386164/batch-script-to-delete-files-based-on-findstr-regex)

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /l %%i in (2,1,6 ) DO (
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b  ^| findstr test_%%i') DO DEL %%a
)
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this batch script

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b | findstr ^.*test_.[0-9]{1}\.txt') DO rd %a
```

Comment: Hi @Rolwin C the above solution is not working .However using this          FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b  ^| findstr test_') DO DEL %%a     i am able to delete all the files with test_ as prefix but not able to delete selected files

Answer (score 0):

You could use,

```
for i in `seq 2 5`; do rm -f test_$i.txt; done
```

That assumes you delete files from test_2.txt to test_5.txt. You should change the numbers if you're going to delete files in a different range.

Comment: This will only work in *NIX-based environments. The question requires a Windows answer.